# reference category in varIdent function (nlme package) depends on data order

Tags: r, variance, nlme

I found that function `varIdent` has an undesired behavior which is dependent on data order. In detail, the reference category depends on data order, see the next example

```r
set.seed(123)
library(tidyverse)
library(nlme)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'nlme'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     collapse

n_smpl<-10
z0<-data.frame(sex=sample(c("F","M"),n_smpl,prob = c(0.6,0.4),replace = T) %>% factor)
summary(z0)
#>  sex  
#>  F:6  
#>  M:4
X<-model.matrix(~sex, z0)

sd_e<-1.3
e<-rnorm(nrow(z0),0,sd_e)
my_bts<-c(10,1.4)

z0$y<-(X %*% my_bts+e)%>% drop

m0<-gls(model=y~sex,weights=varIdent(form=~1|sex),data=z0[order(z0$sex),])
m1<-gls(model=y~sex,weights=varIdent(form=~1|sex),data=z0[order(z0$sex,decreasing =T),])

summary(m0)
#> Generalized least squares fit by REML
#>   Model: y ~ sex 
#>   Data: z0[order(z0$sex), ] 
#>        AIC      BIC    logLik
#>   35.82722 36.14498 -13.91361
#> 
#> Variance function:
#>  Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
#>  Formula: ~1 | sex 
#>  Parameter estimates:
#>         F         M 
#> 1.0000000 0.5305269 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                 Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
#> (Intercept) 10.344227 0.5847687 17.689434  0.0000
#> sexM         0.967754 0.6973690  1.387721  0.2026
#> 
#>  Correlation: 
#>      (Intr)
#> sexM -0.839
#> 
#> Standardized residuals:
#>         Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
#> -1.38845834 -0.72023259 -0.02681155  0.85333098  1.31623645 
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 1.432385 
#> Degrees of freedom: 10 total; 8 residual
summary(m1)
#> Generalized least squares fit by REML
#>   Model: y ~ sex 
#>   Data: z0[order(z0$sex, decreasing = T), ] 
#>        AIC      BIC    logLik
#>   35.82722 36.14498 -13.91361
#> 
#> Variance function:
#>  Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
#>  Formula: ~1 | sex 
#>  Parameter estimates:
#>        M        F 
#> 1.000000 1.884919 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                 Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
#> (Intercept) 10.344227 0.5847687 17.689434  0.0000
#> sexM         0.967754 0.6973690  1.387721  0.2026
#> 
#>  Correlation: 
#>      (Intr)
#> sexM -0.839
#> 
#> Standardized residuals:
#>         Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
#> -1.38845834 -0.72023259 -0.02681155  0.85333098  1.31623645 
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.7599187 
#> Degrees of freedom: 10 total; 8 residual
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Look at `Variance function` outputs for `m0` and `m1` models, the reference category is different in each model. This does not happens in the mean structure component of the model.

Comment: @BenBolker would you help me to report this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug, or at least an infelicity, in `nlme`. If your `sex` variable wasn't already a factor with defined levels I would say it was your fault, or at least expected - but it is.

I have reported this [here](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18505).

A patched version that fixes this problem is available at https://github.com/bbolker/nlme: `remotes::install_github("bbolker/nlme")` to install it (you'll need to have development tools installed to install from source).

A slightly more compact reproducible example:

```r
library(nlme)
dd <- transform(mtcars,
                am = factor(am))
dd <- dd[order(dd$am),]
dd_rev <- dd[order(dd$am, decreasing = TRUE),]

m0 <- gls(mpg ~ hp, weights = varIdent(form = ~1|am), data = dd)
m1 <- update(m0, data = dd_rev)

coef(m0$modelStruct$varStruct)  # 0.9776946
coef(m1$modelStruct$varStruct)  # -0.9776946
```